# how to diff two "identical" device tree blobs

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

Right now I have two nvidia kernel 4-4 device tree blobs that are created on two different computers at different times.  The source/git commit for these blobs are identical.  Unfortunately, the md5sums of the blobs differ.  When I decompile these blobs, they are identical except that they store build time and path info making it non-hermetic.

Right now I'm planning on decompiling and filling in those fields as constants, then taking the md5sum of those files to tell if they are different.  Is there a better way to do this?

[image: Only difference in decompiled blobs]

Comment: Don't use microscopic image files, please!

Comment: It sounds like DT compile is not able to produce same binaries from the same source if runs twice in raw. You can file bug against DT compiler.

Comment: @0andriy, if you click on the image the full-sized image is viewable...